# Não consigo importar dados numericos ou datas com campos vazios no postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Quando qualquer coluna dom tipo numeric ou date está em branco ocorre erro na importação

**DADOS A IMPORTAR:**

```
NU_ANO_CENSO|CO_ENTIDADE|DT_ANO_LETIVO_INICIO|DT_ANO_LETIVO_TERMINO|NU_LATITUDE|NU_LONGITUDE
2017|15547000|06/03/2017|29/12/2017|-1.4708028364433|-48.477029371433
2017|15060381|13/02/2017|28/12/2017|-1.9599968499001|-48.204413671799
2017|15060411|13/02/2017|28/12/2017|                |
2017|15079562|02/03/2017|          |-5.2885284042542|-52.486146949226
```

**TIPOS DOS CAMPOS:**

```
create table ESCOLA_2017
(
NU_ANO_CENSO                  NUMERIC(4),
CO_ENTIDADE                   NUMERIC(8),
DT_ANO_LETIVO_INICIO          DATE,
DT_ANO_LETIVO_TERMINO         DATE,
NU_LATITUDE                   NUMERIC(20,17),
NU_LONGITUDE                  NUMERIC(20,17));
```

**Comando p/ importação:**

```
COPY ESCOLA_2017 FROM 'C:/CriacaoDB/ESCOLA_2017.txt' using delimiters '|';
```

**MENSAGEM DE ERRO:**

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""
CONTEXT:  COPY ts_escola_17_2, line 2, column nu_latitude: ""
SQL state: 22P02

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: ""
CONTEXT:  COPY ts_escola_17_2, line 2, column dt_ano_letivo_termino: ""
SQL state: 22007
```

Answer (score 0):

A solução vai ser bem simples.

Você só precisa indicar as aspas duplas em "Quote options".

Depois de fazer o COPY todo você pode indicar as aspas com QUOTE, mas o valor padrão já é aspas-duplas e isso só funciona para arquivos .CSV, logo, **minha recomendação nesse caso é usar a extensão .CSV, em vez de .TXT**, e tentar importar normalmente, indicando o delimitador "|" (pipe).

Answer (score 0):

Alguns campos do seu arquivo `CSV` de origem parecem estar `em branco`.

Você precisa dizer ao comando `COPY` para interpretar esses campos em branco como se eles fossem `NULL`, vejamos:

```
COPY
     ESCOLA_2017
FROM
     'C:/CriacaoDB/ESCOLA_2017.txt'
USING
     DELIMITER '|'
     NULL '';
```

Referência: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-copy.html